# Display contents of log file with lines in reverse order (Last shall be First) in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy script that logs into a device and dumps its log file into a variable. The problem is the way its stored in the device. It starts with the oldest event first with the most recent at the end. I will be displaying this log file on a web page and no one will want to scroll down to the bottom of a large log file to see the most recent event. This how the data looks (condensed) after I get now:

```
03/11/20 08:20:58 LocationALPHA 1.1.0.1 Device Failure ping :: Critical :: down
03/11/20 08:25:58 LocationALPHA 1.1.0.1 Device Failure ping :: Critical :: down (reminder)
06/27/20 18:01:11 LocationGAMMA 2.1.0.1 GEN AUX FAULT :: Critical :: ACTIVE
06/27/20 18:11:25 LocationGAMMA 2.1.0.1 GEN AUX FAULT :: Critical :: INACTIVE
12/20/20 10:53:43 BETA_MAIN (r42324) 2.3.3.3 SignalLoss SIG FAIL :: Critical :: ACTIVE
```

And here is how I would like to see it for display on webpage:

```
12/20/20 10:53:43 BETA_MAIN (r42324) 2.3.3.3 SignalLoss SIG FAIL :: Critical :: ACTIVE
06/27/20 18:11:25 LocationGAMMA 2.1.0.1 GEN AUX FAULT :: Critical :: INACTIVE
06/27/20 18:01:11 LocationGAMMA 2.1.0.1 GEN AUX FAULT :: Critical :: ACTIVE
03/11/20 08:25:58 LocationALPHA 1.1.0.1 Device Failure ping :: Critical :: down (reminder)
03/11/20 08:20:58 LocationALPHA 1.1.0.1 Device Failure ping :: Critical :: down
```

I'm going to try and make the contents of the variable a list, not sure how that will go. I would appreciate any suggestions. And I'll have to make the changes with groovy.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple one-liner would do what you want:

```
String input = '''
03/11/20 08:20:58 LocationALPHA 1.1.0.1 Device Failure ping :: Critical :: down
03/11/20 08:25:58 LocationALPHA 1.1.0.1 Device Failure ping :: Critical :: down (reminder)
06/27/20 18:01:11 LocationGAMMA 2.1.0.1 GEN AUX FAULT :: Critical :: ACTIVE
06/27/20 18:11:25 LocationGAMMA 2.1.0.1 GEN AUX FAULT :: Critical :: INACTIVE
12/20/20 10:53:43 BETA_MAIN (r42324) 2.3.3.3 SignalLoss SIG FAIL :: Critical :: ACTIVE'''

println input.readLines().reverse().join( '\n' )
```

prints:

```
12/20/20 10:53:43 BETA_MAIN (r42324) 2.3.3.3 SignalLoss SIG FAIL :: Critical :: ACTIVE
06/27/20 18:11:25 LocationGAMMA 2.1.0.1 GEN AUX FAULT :: Critical :: INACTIVE
06/27/20 18:01:11 LocationGAMMA 2.1.0.1 GEN AUX FAULT :: Critical :: ACTIVE
03/11/20 08:25:58 LocationALPHA 1.1.0.1 Device Failure ping :: Critical :: down (reminder)
03/11/20 08:20:58 LocationALPHA 1.1.0.1 Device Failure ping :: Critical :: down
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for, works perfect. Thank you.